# Remedy for failure to hear Agenda Item

Tags: florida, remedy

Florida [FS 718.112](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0718/Sections/0718.112.html) requires condominium to:

> If 20 percent of the voting interests petition the board to address an
> item of business, the board, within 60 days after receipt of the
> petition, shall place the item on the agenda at its next regular board
> meeting or at a special meeting called for that purpose.

Assume that the Association fails to follow the rule and fails to hear the agenda item and the business item is under Arbitration / Litigation.  What is the appropriate monetary and non-monetary remedy to request?

I was unable to find a remedy in the statute.

Comment: The statute you referenced doesn't appear to provide any remedies other than the recall process for HOA directors who don't do their jobs.  But if you are damaged in some way as a result of their failure to address the issue raised, then you may want to look at a court case.

Comment: I assume that by "hear" you mean "consider deliberatively." Reading the title, I initially assumed that this was an auditory reception disability related question.

Answer (score 3):

> If 20 percent of the voting interests petition the board to address an
> item of business, the board, within 60 days after receipt of the
> petition, shall place the item on the agenda at its next regular board
> meeting or at a special meeting called for that purpose.
>
> Assume that the Association fails to follow the rule and fails to hear
> the agenda item and the business item is under Arbitration /
> Litigation. What is the appropriate monetary and non-monetary remedy
> to request?

A Petition for a Writ of Mandamus or affirmative injunction ordering the board to consider the matter, depending upon the customs of Florida courts would be the usual remedy. But, one can imagine a fact pattern where some other relief such as also allowing money damages would be appropriate where, for example, delay impacts the cost of doing work.